# jQuery Selection Problem

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

In the following code, how do I select all the `<tr>` elements that have a `<td>` with an image that ends in `cancelled.png`? I am at a loss...

```
<table>
    <tr> <----- select this whole tr
        <td>
            <img src="/images/icons/invoice-cancelled.png" alt="cancelled" />
            <a href='/orders/invoice.aspx?invoiceid=63'>X1087</a>
        </td>
        ... other tds, some with "-cancelled.png" others with something different
    </tr>
    ....
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('tr:has(td img[src$="cancelled.png"])')
```

Explanation:

```
(tr) Select All Table Rows
(:has()) That Have:
(td) a table data
(img) with an image in it
([src$="cancelled.png"]) that has an ttribute of 'src' that ends($=) in 
                         'cancelled.png'
```